# python plot using pylab

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm very new to python just started using it from a day or two..
I'm using Anaconda python notebook.
so I'm trying to plot, but in the output there is only grid and nothing no lines or anything,
my program is as follows

```
from __future__ import print_function
from decimal import *
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
import pylab

k = Symbol('k')
A = Symbol('A')
E = Symbol('E')
d = Symbol('d')
C = Symbol('C')
Y = Symbol('Y')

Y = []

for A in np.arange(-1.11, 1.11, 0.002):        
    s = sin(A)
    c = cos(A)
    C = (s/A) + c
    Y.append(C)      

pylab.plot(C, A)   
grid()

xlabel('$x$')
ylabel('$y$')

title('graph')
```

The code doesn't show any errors, but will you please help me as to what am I doing wrong here ...

Comment: You replace the symbol Y with the array.

Comment: isn't putting 
Y = []
same as defining Y as array?

Comment: The line before you have defined Y as Symbol('Y')

Comment: oh!! ok, so I removed that line and directly kept Y = [], but still didn't work..

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing different plotting functions from pylab, sympy and you are not giving an X axis:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
Y=[]
X = np.arange(-1.11, 1.11, 0.002)
for A in X:
     s = np.sin(A)
     c = np.cos(A)
     C = (s/A)+c
     Y.append(C)
line, = pyplot.plot(X,Y, "-b")
pyplot.grid(True)
pyplot.show()
```

Gives me:
[image]

Comment: Well, OP _tried_ to give an x axis, but using A... which, after the loop, is not a list but the last element of its `arange` call.

Comment: The OP code and problems also nicely illiterates why ever doing from pppp import * is a bad idea, doing it more than once is a __really__ bad idea!

Comment: Respected Steve, thank you so much, for your help.. I will try to keep this mistakes in check from next time.. really appreciate your help..

Comment: Steve, what do you mean by -- The OP code and problems also nicely illiterates why ever doing from pppp import * is a bad idea, doing it more than once is a really bad idea!

Comment: what does '-b' in 'line = pyplot.plot(X,Y, "-b") represent?

Comment: grid is coming from sympy rather than pylab or pyplot, decimal isn't doing anything, (probably), where are sin & cos coming from, etc., the _problem_ with from ... import * is that you loose your namespaces so you can't see if you are mixing models. **'-b'** says I would like lines - rather than . points or x's and I would like them blue rather than red or black.

Answer (score 1):

What about showing the graph with

```
 pylab.show()
```

Comment: well, after replacing pylab.plot(C, A) with pylab.show(C, A), I get the following error     C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.pyc in show(*args, **kw)
    143     """
    144     global _show
--> 145     _show(*args, **kw)
    146 
    147 

TypeError: show() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: Oz123's answers only suggested that `pylab.show()` command is to be __added_ at the bottom of your code, as last line, not as replacement to `pylab.plot(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I do this, I have a figure with both grid and graph:

```
import pylab
pylab.plot([1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3])
pylab.grid()
pylab.show()
```

But if I do this, I have first a figure with only the graph, and then with only the grid:

```
import pylab
pylab.plot([1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3])
pylab.show()  # here I get only the graph
pylab.grid()
pylab.show()  # here I get only the grid
```

Note: calling `grid()`, `title()`, `xlabel` and `ylabel` as you do shall not work; each time it shall be prepended by `pylab.`. Is that really your code?

Comment: yeah, that is my own code that I wrote after going through some webpages and stuff.. thanks for your help, And I'm confused about writing the  variable = Symbol('Variable') each time as I did in my program so how to get around that problem?

Comment: What were you trying to achieve with that?  The reason that grid, etc, don't give an error is the `from sympy import *` so those bits use sympy and the pylab uses pylab....